# Sort all dimensions of a cell array from min to max in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have created a cell array called `Items` of size `(10,5)`. It contains the following as the first column in the cell array:

```
Item name    Price (in $)    Shipping (in $)    Total price (in $)    Total price (in €)
```

I have it all filled up, but what I need to do is to sort the cell array according to the total price in € from the smallest to the largest, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I tried `sort(Items,5);` in order to sort according to the values in € but it returns an error. It could be useful to find a way to make the sorting automatic, so if I wanted to add more items it would still sort them in the global list.

Comment: is your cell array simply a matrix with the top row being headers and the rest being numbers? Either way, look into the `sortrows` function

Comment: In the first column I have the item names (string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html?refresh=true) will likely do exactly what you want to do. It will sort based on a specific column, assuming the datatype is constant in the entire column.

```
>> a ={'a',8,9;'b',5,6;'c',2,3};
>> a_sorted = sortrows(a,3)

a_sortred = 

'c'    [2]    [3]
'b'    [5]    [6]
'a'    [8]    [9]
```

**Edit**

From your comments below, you can easily just sort the array first and then add a row to the cell array the same way you would combine regular arrays. [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html)

```
>> a = {7,8,9;4,5,6;1,2,3};
>> a_sorted = sortrows(a,3);
>> headers = {'col1','col2','col3'};
>> a_header = [headers;a_sorted]

a_header = 

    'col1'    'col2'    'col3'
    [   1]    [   2]    [   3]
    [   4]    [   5]    [   6]
    [   7]    [   8]    [   9]
```

**EDIT #2**

You can round the values that you are presenting using the second argument of the [round](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) function. After you round it, you can change the format of how things are displayed. Normally it is set as `short`, which is 4 decimal places. If you set it to `shortg` it will show as few decimals as possible, up to 4.

```
>> a = [1.23456789;2.3456789;3.456789]

a =

    1.2346
    2.3457
    3.4568

>> a_rounded = round(a,2)

a_rounded =

    1.2300
    2.3500
    3.4600

>> format shortg
>> a_rounded

a_rounded =

         1.23
         2.35
         3.46
```

If changing the format is not an option, you could always just convert the number into a string and then display that. That gets a little more complicated, but a quick google will help you there.

**EDIT #3**

I did not know this existed before, but you can apparently use the format [style](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#inputarg_style) called `bank`. This will display all numbers as two decimal points even if they are 0.

Comment: Your method worked just fine. By the way, how do you put titles to the columns? Is there a specific way to do it, or is just the first row of the cell?

Comment: @MartaSampietro Use the `table` class or place a row of strings as the first column of your cell array.

Comment: @MartaSampietro rayryeng's suggestion is exactly what you want to do. However, if you do this, the sortrow function will not work if you add a top row to your cell array since it assumes that the entire column is the same datatype.

Comment: What if I sorted it and in the end, just before displaying it, I added the title row? Still don't know how to add the row though...

Comment: @MartaSampietro Yes, sort the cell array first then add the names after.  Something like this will work: `names = {'Item name', 'Price (in $)', 'Shipping (in $)', 'Total price (in $)','Total price (in €)'};
asorted = [names; asorted];`  This first creates a cell array of names as a single row then we concatenate this names cell array to be at the top of the sorted array.

Comment: @MartaSampietro Edit added to my answer, explaining what you want, Also please remember to accept an answer so future people searching know what answered your question.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Perfect. Now it works just fine! Just to be a little bit picky, is there any way to have the numbers on the list be stored with only two decimals? For example 17.48, or 9.95, or 0.00 in case of free shipment? In the end I am showing the table with `disp(Items)` so it would be nice to have the same format for all numbers.

Comment: The edit works fine except for the ones that should be .00 but are simply an integer. Is there a way to store them with the .00?

Comment: @MartaSampietro I just read the documentation, you can use `format bank`. Added to my answer. Please remember to accept whatever answer helped you.

Answer (score 2):

First place all of the prices in a separate array, sort on this array individually then use the indices of sorting to rearrange the rows of your cell array.

Try something like this:

```
price = [Items{:,5}];
[~,ind] = sort(price);
ItemsSorted = Items(ind,:);
```

---

Alternatively you can use the [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) function that MZimmerman6 mentioned and operate along the fifth column of your cell array.  I wasn't aware it worked on cell arrays, so I learned something new!

Comment: glad to teach you something new :) I just learned about it a couple months ago. Though the alternative is only one or two lines more, conciseness is almost always good.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I didn't know it worked on cell arrays which is why I didn't think twice about using it.  Thanks for the trick!

Comment: no problem, it even works on table as well apparently, just read that in the documentation.